# Ubuntu does not boot with regular option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair, recovery-mode

At the beginning, I get a screen like this

[image]

If I click on first option *ubuntu*, the ubuntu does not boot up. It keeps showing a purple screen.

So, then I select the option 2 - *Advanced options for ubuntu*.

I get a screen similar to -
[image]

with one more option per version i.e.
ubuntu, with linux  - generic (systemmd)

if I choose any (systemmd) or (recovery mode) option from the Advanced options, ubuntu boots well.

There are 3, 4 different versions already and increasing.

How do I get rid of all this and make my ubuntu work normally?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: On he first screen you referenced ("regular option"), hit the letter `e`.  Then using the arrow keys navigate to and remove the words `quiet` and `splash`.  Then hit `F10` to boot.  Show us where it stops.

Comment: Did you use the `ENTER` key to actually select the first Ubuntu option? What happens when you try to boot any of the choices in the advanced menu? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Yes I do use Enter key. And forgot to mention that - if I choose any (systemmd) or (recovery mode) option from the Advanced options, ubuntu boots well.

Comment: Boot Ubuntu using advanced options, open terminal, and type `sudo update-grub`, then reboot. See if that doesn't fix the problem. Cheers, Al